# WordPress (elementer)

Tags: wordpress, fonts, vs-web-site-project

I am facing problem in WordPress website. In elementer plugin I changed font colours,but didn't apply.when I login to website it will show black font, but I log out into my panel it will show light blue colour.how do I change the font colours.please someone give me solution.

Thanku

Answer (score 0):

1. Change font color in editor and apply changes.
2. Check and reset your cache if you have.